# Calculate season prices

Tags: php

I want to calculate season prices.
The beginning and ending dates of the seasons should be 'the last Saturday of this month' instead of '2016-31-12'.

The only problem for me is that I don't know how to loop trough the array called 'period' when there is a period booked with a different year number.
To clear things up, 'the last Saturday of this month' changes in the next year.

Example:

```
$beginseason1 = new DateTime('December');
$beginseason1->modify('last saturday of this month');
```

My code:

```
<?php
// declare season dates
$startdate = new DateTime('2016-12-31');
$enddate = new DateTime('2018-04-30');

$beginseason1 = new DateTime('2016-01-01');
$endseason1 = new DateTime('2016-03-30');

$beginseason2 = new DateTime('2016-03-31');
$endseason2 = new DateTime('2016-04-30');

$beginseason3 = new DateTime('2016-05-01');
$endseason3 = new DateTime('2016-12-31');

// get period of booked dates and put them in a array
$period = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime($startdate->format('Y-m-d')),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime($enddate->format('Y-m-d'))
);

//declare variables below
$price = 0;
$daysinseason1 = 0;
$daysinseason2 = 0;
$daysinseason3 = 0;

// loop trough array and check every date with season prices
foreach($period as $date)
{
    if($date->format('m-d') >= $beginseason1->format('m-d') && $date- >format('m-d') <= $endseason1->format('m-d')){
        echo $date->format('m-d') . "<br/>";
        $price = $price + 25;
        $daysinseason1++;
}
    if($date->format('m-d') >= $beginseason2->format('m-d') && $date->format('m-d') <= $endseason2->format('m-d')){
        echo $date->format('m-d') . "<br/>";
        $price = $price + 25;
        $daysinseason2++;
    }
    if($date->format('m-d') >= $beginseason3->format('m-d') && $date->format('m-d') <= $endseason3->format('m-d')){
        echo $date->format('m-d') . "<br/>";
        $price = $price + 25;
        $daysinseason3++;
    }
}
echo "season 1: " . $daysinseason1  . "<br/>";
echo "season 2: " . $daysinseason2  . "<br/>";
echo "season 3: " . $daysinseason3  . "<br/>";
?>
```

My code does the trick but it doesn't matter if the year is 2016 or 2018 31-12 is alway the last Saturday of December.
And also the beginning of season 1 occur in 2016 but the ending in 2017.

How can I program this the right way?

Comment: in php you can use relative date to build a new datetime. perhaps this can solve your problem `new Datetime('last sunday of december 2016')`